# Flipping an image and then referencing that image in html

Tags: html, css, image

Sorry if none of this makes sense and if my formatting is poor (I'm *very* new to coding). I'm trying to create a page where I have an image and it mirrors itself horizontally every second or so. Essentially the image flips back and forth forever. I was able to get the timer thing to work so it changes between the two images every second, and I was also able to create the mirrored image, but I don't know how to reference it elsewhere in the code. Like I don't know how to label           images[1]="theflippedimage" or something. Here's what I have so far:

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        function nextImage(){
            x = (x === images.length - 1) ? 0 : x + 1;
            document.getElementById("img").src=images[x];
        }
        function previousImage() {
            x = (x <=0) ? images.length - 1: x - 1;
            document.getElementById("img").src=images[x];
        }
        function startTimer() {
            setInterval(nextImage,1000);
        }
        var images= [], x= -1;

         images[0]="http://www.honda-perf.net/images/thumbs/cat.jpg"

            <img style='border:0';
            transform:scale(-1,1); 
            -webkit-transform:scale(-1,1);
            -moz-transform:scale(-1,1);
            -o-transform:scale(-1,1);
            src="http://www.honda-perf.net/images/thumbs/cat.jpg/>;
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="startTimer()">
    <img id="img" src="http://www.honda-perf.net/images/thumbs/cat.jpg">
</body>
```

Comment: There is no way that HTML / javascript code actually works.

Comment: please include a fiddle

Comment: Where are you using `previousImage()`

Comment: Oh I guess I don't need the previousImage() function.

Comment: The code that I wrote doesn't work, I am aware. If I were to use a second .jpg for images[1], I would get the two images alternating back and forth. My issue is that I want to alternate between one photo and its mirror.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The effect can be achieved relatively easy using CSS animations.

In your html you will have the body element containing an image with an id of `img` as in your example:

```
<body>
    <img id="img" src="http://www.honda-perf.net/images/thumbs/cat.jpg">
</body>
```

The animation using CSS3 would look like this:

```
#img {
    -webkit-animation: horizontalflip 5s infinite;
    -moz-animation:    horizontalflip 5s infinite;
    -o-animation:      horizontalflip 5s infinite;
    /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    animation: horizontalflip 5s infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes horizontalflip {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(-1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}

@-moz-keyframes horizontalflip {
   0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(-1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}

@-o-keyframes horizontalflip {
   0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(-1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}

@keyframes horizontalflip {
   0% {
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(-1,1);
    }
    100%{
        transform: scale(1,1);
    }
}
```

The code above works in all the modern browsers supporting CSS 3. The explanation for the animation code would be that:

1. On the `#img` element I run an animation, which I named `horizontalflip`. The full animation takes 5 seconds to complete and it will run infinitely. You can change the time value to something that you consider fit if 5 seconds seem too much.
2. The next blocks of code (that contain `@-vendorprefix-keyframes`) describe what happens with the animation. Every 2.5 seconds (50% of the time defined at point 1), the image mirrors itself horizontally. The animation itself is pretty trivial, but you have to do each vendor prefix individually.

Working JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vuc4pxsk/1/

I hope I understood correctly your requirements.

For more information about CSS 3 animations, please see: 
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/